# My iframe is outside of it's section container and I can't position it inside

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I can't figure out why my iframe is outside of the section it is in.
[Here](https://envyme.github.io/Wok-N-Roll/) is a link to my github pages site and [here](https://github.com/EnvyMe/Wok-N-Roll) is the repo. Thanks for any help!

[image: the overflowing iframe]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container ID only has a height of 300px.

```
#contact-us{
  height:300px;
  padding:5%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Changing its height to 400px better accomodates the iframe, without overflowing its section.

```
#contact-us{
  height:400px;
  padding:5%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Then your map view will be aligned correctly.

Comment: This apppears to have fixed it, I have a follow up question. The section above my contact-us section appears to have a large empty space at the bottom. If you hover the section in chrome dev tools you can see what I mean. Do you know why this is?

Comment: you can try to decrease top padding from contact-us section 
#contact-us {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0 5%;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe looks perfectly inside of the section it is in. You should check out your question again and ask the right question about the difficulty you are actually facing. Then only anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, maybe my browser is displaying it differently. I attatched an image to my original post to show you what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```
.map-container {
position: relative;
bottom: 130px; 
}
```

And in your iframe width="100%"